# Understanding Integrate output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I set the function,

```
f = Log[Abs[1-x(1-x)*a]]
```

And I want to integrate within the interval of {x,0,1} with the assumption that "a" is a Real parameter. So I type,

```
Integrate[f,{x,0,1},Assumptions -> {Element[a,Reals]}]
```

Which gives me the output:

```
expression1  a<4
expression2  true
```

My question is, the first expression is my answer for a<4 but what does the second expression means? Is it my answer if a>4?

Comment: `Piecewise` returns the value associated with the first condition that is true. If all conditions are false, the last "default" value, indicated by the condition `True` is returned. So it's the value for `a >= 4` (or any value for which `a < 4` is `False`).  See the documentation for `Piecewise`.

Comment: In addition, a < 4 implies that a is an element of the Reals.

Comment: I get a different answer different answer using 13.1. But, it reduces to your form if I wrap FullSimpillfy around the result.  However, expression2 appears to be incorrect which can be verified using NIntegrate[expr/.a->Sqrt[-1],{x,0,1}].  I believe that this will be fixed in 13.2

Comment: Ditto for NIntegrate[f /. a -> 6, {x, 0, 1}]

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, OK with the `RealAbs` instead of `Abs` in 13.1 on Windows 10.

```
f = Log[RealAbs[1 - x*(1 - x)*a]];
Integrate[f, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {Element[a, Reals]}]
```

> `Piecewise[ {{2*(-1 + Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]*ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]]),  a <= 4}}, Integrate[Log[RealAbs[1 - a*(1 - x)*x]],  {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Element[a, Reals] && a > 4]]`

It should be noticed that this is a session depending result. Sometimes I obtain

> `Piecewise[ {{2*(-1 + Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]*ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]]),  a <= 4}}, (-4 - (4*I)*Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]*Pi +  2*Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]*Log[-4 + a] + Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]* Log[1/2 + (-4 + a)^(-1) + Sqrt[a/(-4 + a)]/2] -  Sqrt[(-4 + a)/a]*Log[((-4 + a)*(a - Sqrt[(-4 + a)*a]))/ (a + Sqrt[(-4 + a)*a])])/2]`

which is not correct for `a>4`.

Comment: Why do you say this given answer is not correct for a>4?